# Stripe Payments Gateway Automation

Tags: php, stripe-payments

So I was recently trying my hands on Stripe Payments Gateway using PHP

I could make it and its working absolutely fine, just the fact that it lags something, if I go to the index.php page this shows me a pay with card button, **I want it to initiate the payment without having to click that button as soon as I go to the index.php page**.

I did try it but I wasn't successful. My Current Codes are as follows :

```
<?php
require('config.php');
$amount= $_GET['amount'];
$total = $amount * 100;


?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Stripe Checkout </title>
        </head>
        <body>
<body onload= "submitter()">
<form action="submit.php" method="post" id="stripeForm">
    <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="<?php echo $publishableKey?>"
        data-amount="<?php echo"$total";?>"
        data-name="XyberNeo Digital Solutions"
        data-description="Classic Starter Plan"
        data-image="https://www.xyberneo.com/cloudsheets/v3/assets/img/favicon.png"
        data-currency="inr"
        data-email="aditya@xyberneo.com"
    >
    </script>


      </form>
      <script>
      function submitter(){
          document.getElementById("stripe-button").submit()
      }
      </script >
    <body>
<html>
```

It would be really amazing if someone could guide me on how I can modify the codes and get my purpose satisfied.

Thanks a lot for your time

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

Initiating payment on load probably won't work without some events like a button click. Assuming your code works, it's still lacking payment methods information. If you're doing purely client-only integration, see https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment on how to confirm a card payment.

If you're doing both server and client-side integration, you can attempt to immediately `confirm` a `PaymentIntent` upon creation, see https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-confirm.

It would help if you could share more about your business flow and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, basically I am creating a web hook that I can use from any browser/app or any platform. So the issue is for suppose am using it in an android app, I will use a web viewer to display the page, but that button is destroying the ui and user experience. So am looking for a way to run that button's function as soon as someone hits that web url with the parameters

Comment: Please refer to Stripe JS documentation on whether whatever you're trying to implement is possible. From the looks of it, it isn't. Since you're developing an android app, make use of Stripe Android SDK. That way you don't have to embed any webview whatsoever, since UI/UX is also your concern.